# Casting different from bit manipulation

Tags: solidity, bytes, math, bit-manipulation

Casting between `uint`s and `bytes16` yields different results as that of manipulating the bits directly.

Why? I thought that with casting we were just changing the representation from bits to bytes, and vice versa, but the core numbers stayed the same.

```js
uint b = 54802476401439357 * 1e18;
uint base = 1108895170451311786;
uint b_prime = uint(uint128(bytes16(uint128(base)).ln()));
uint b_prime2 = base.fromUInt().ln().toUInt();

console.log('prime: ', b_prime); //----> 255276110499392941787653382584691046923
console.log('prime2: ', b_prime2);// ---> 42
```

The `fromUInt()`, `toUInt()`, and `ln()` functions can be found on [ABDKMathQuad's library](https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/master/ABDKMathQuad.sol).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that the library assumes that `bytes16` is *IEEE 754 quadruple-precision binary floating-point numbers*.

If you look at the conversion functions `fromUint`, `toUint`, etc. they are quite complex because they have to pack or unpack the IEEE floating point format.

On the other hand the *solidity* casting `bytes16(uint128(base))` doesn't known anything about floating point numbers. In this case itt doesn't do anything at the EVM level, because the types are of the same length. It is a semantic conversion to prevent type conversion of bugs.